# How to get Interval or similar classes in Joda Time in a desired time format?

Tags: java, jodatime

My interval has an start DateTime and an end DateTime. How do I format the Interval or its DateTimes such that I only get the parts that i want. For example, only Date eg `2012-04-11` followed by time `06:15:25` and nothing else.

Comment: Will java.text.SimpleDateFormat help?? yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) , you can pass in which format you want.

For example

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

Comment: @JediKnight: It was a redundant. Removed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried PeriodFormatter: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html